# tune query to avoid using aggregate function with order by

Tags: sql, hibernate

how can i rewrite the below query to avoid the use of aggegate function with order by :

**select id from my_table where flow='REQ' and audit_time <= '04-Jul-2014' group by (id) order by min(audit_time);**

since i have a large data set, the above query is causing performance issues.
below is a sample data:

pk | id | audit_time  | flow
 
1  | 1  | 10-Jul-2014 | REQ
2  | 1  | 05-Jul-2014 | REQ
3  | 2  | 03-Jul-2014 | REQ
4  | 2  | 01-Jul-2014 | RES
5  | 1  | 04-Jul-2014 | RES

In output, i want to have the unique id list sorted by time.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Doesn't your query work?

Comment: the query works, but i think the "order by min(audit_time)" is increasing the cost of the query. I want to make it more performance efficient, as my table has a lot of data.

Comment: Hibernate is not as rich as SQL.  I'm not sure if there is any other way to express this query.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need group by id because id will be unique(It should be) and you are not joining any table
then you just have to order it by audit_time. And as you are not doing group by you don't need to use function in order by.

```
select id from my_table where flow='REQ' and audit_time <= '04-Jul-2014' order by audit_time;
```

If your ID is not unique and you want to order by minimum audit_time then your query is the only way(IMO).